# Toast positioning not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I tired this bit of code:

```
Toast toast = new Toast(this); 
            toast.setText("Please enter your User-Id");
            toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
            toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
            toast.show();
```

But still the toast is getting displayed at the bottom which is the default. Even this below one is also not working:

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
```

Please help.

Regards,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should NOT use the constructor of the Toast class.

Do the following:

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your User-Id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
toast.show();
```

Comment: Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter your User-Id", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0).show();

This line is giving compilation error:
"Cannot invoke show() on primitive type void"

Comment: I think only the first piece of code will work properly. They are effectively the same in terms of what they will accomplish.

Comment: Yes, the first piece of code is working perfectly!!! But the second piexe of code is having compilation errors!!!

Comment: Yeah, My mistake. I removed it.